# Make a changing number more probable in Python

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I have 6 colours associated with the values 1 to 6 that are all equally probable:

```
    randc = random.randint(1,6)
    if randc == 1:
        print 'red'
    elif randc == 2:
        print 'green'
    elif randc == 3:
        print 'purple'
    elif randc == 4:
        print 'yellow'
    elif randc == 5:
        print 'orange'
    elif randc == 6:
        print 'brown'
```

Now I want a second colour to print such that 50% of the time it will be the same as the first colour.  In the past I have used numpy to augment probability, but I only makes a set value more probable:

```
    randcol = numpy.random.choice((1,2), p=[0.8, 0.2])
    if randcol == 1:
        print 'red'  # will occur 80% of the time
    elif randcol == 2:
        print 'green' # will occur 20% of the time
```

How do I change the probability such that it will make a previous selection more likely?

Comment: On a side note, you may want to take a look at Enumerated types for assigning a color a number: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: don't understand your question, do you want to make sort of [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `p` or the input every time you call it.

```
colors = ['red', 'green', 'purple', 'yellow', 'orange', 'brown']
prev_choice = numpy.random.choice(colors)
print(prev_choice)
# pick the first color uniformly.

for _ in range(100):
    prev_choice = numpy.random.choice([prev_choice] + colors, p=[0.4] + [0.1]*6)
    print(prev_choice)
    # we pick the new color same as the previous one with 40% chance,
    # and all of the colors uniformly with 10% each.
    # (so the total chance of choosing the previous color is 40% + 10% = 50%)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this without using numpy or any other library,

```
randc = random.randint(1,6)
probList = range(1,7) + [randc]*4
next = probList[random.randint(0,len(probList)-1)]
```

next will have the 50% probability you wanted.

Since the probList will be filled with 5 times the last color out of 10, it is 50% probability. And for the rest of the colors probability is equally divided.

Example:

Lets say `randC= 5`

Now probList will become

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,5,5,5,5]
```

Thus getting 5 from the above list will have a probability of 50%.